# QField displaying incomplete base map

Tags: qfield

Exporting a project with OSM as a base map for offline usage and importing everything in the device, the base map loads only partially as for the two projects in the following pic.

[image]

I tried to change the generation parameters (tile size,mupp) but I still get the same results (and worsening speed in case of high detail/big size values). Years ago I had similar problems with the QGIS print composer that were related to a slow connection, but it is definitely not the case now. Any other parameter I'm missing?

I'm using QGIS 3.22.7 on W10 and the latest QField/QFieldSync (but it happened also previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one year, I randomly stumbled upon the solution!
It seems that the exported basemap is only the one visualised in the main map canvas. So I had to zoom to the biggest layer extent and then pack the project to see the basemap fully exported. It looks to me a weird behaviour but so it is.
I hope this may help others!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it works, but when setting the project properties, have you tried to set the OSM layer as Base Map?

Project > Properties > QField then select the QFieldCloud or Cable Export panel depending on your needs and set as in the image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately those are my actual settings...

Comment: Any other additional info about your settings?

Comment: nothing in particular more than the fact that, while packaging, I get a warning because some vector layers are not in UTF-8

Comment: Have you tried to create a different test project, maybe on a different device, just to see if it's a persistent issue?

Comment: it happens with all my projects both on my smartphones and my tablet

Answer (score 1):

I you have other (unnecessary) offline maps like mbtiles or raster maps in *gpkg files in the project, try deleting them (just as the themes based on those) . Then configure the OSM base map based on a single layer (a xyz OpenStreetMap). In my experience it renders then fluently offline. I have the impression that other offline raster maps make the use of the base map more complicated... Perhaps this is also the case in your project(s).